# Reading from /dev/random does not produce any data

Tags: linux, random

I often use the command

```
cat /dev/urandom | strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t ' | head --bytes 32
```

to generate pseudo-random passwords. This doesn't work with `/dev/random`.

Specifically

- `cat /dev/urandom | strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t '` produces output
- `cat  /dev/random | strings --bytes 1` produces output
- `cat  /dev/random | strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t  '` **does not** produce output

NB: When using `/dev/random` you may have to wiggle your mouse or press keys (e.g. ctrl, shift, etc.) to generate entropy.

**Why does the last example not work?** Does `tr` have some kind of large internal buffer that `/dev/urandom` fills quickly but `/dev/random` doesn't?

P.S. I'm using CentOS 6.5

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014
```

Comment: what is your distribution , your kernel version ? on Cygwin both return values.

Comment: @Kiwy See edit.

Comment: You do know [`pwgen`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/), in particular `pwgen -s`?

Comment: @MvG An interesting project, built not reliably included in any distributions as far as I know. Also memorable passwords will be less random, so not quite right for my application. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should use makepasswd utility.

Comment: The `-s` switch makes them less memorable, more truly random. @Boyd: is [makepasswd](http://packages.debian.org/source/sid/makepasswd) widely available beyond the Debian-based distros? The way I see it, [pwgen is available for CentOS](http://pkgs.org/download/pwgen) while [makepasswd is not](http://pkgs.org/download/makepasswd).

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. I concur with @ MvG that `makepasswd` isn't available on my platform, thanks anyway

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It will eventually.

In:

```
cat /dev/random | strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t '
```

`cat` will never buffer, but it's superfluous anyway as there's nothing to concatenate here.

```
< /dev/random strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t '
```

`strings` though, since its output is not longer a terminal will buffer its output by blocks (of something like 4 or 8kB) as opposed to *lines* when the output goes to a terminal.

So it will only start writing to stdout when it has accumulated 4kB worth of characters to output, which on `/dev/random` is going to take a while.

`tr` output goes to a terminal (if you're running that at a shell prompt in a terminal), so it will buffer its output line-wise. Because you're removing the `\n`, it will never have a full line to write, so instead, it will write as soon as a full block has been accumulated (like when the output doesn't go to a terminal).

So, `tr` is likely not to write anything until `strings` has read enough from `/dev/random` so as to write 8kB (2 blocks possibly much more) of data (since the first block will probably contain some newline or tab or space characters).

On this system I'm trying this on, I can get an average of 3 bytes per second from `/dev/random` (as opposed to 12MiB on `/dev/urandom`), so in the best case scenario (the first 4096 bytes from `/dev/random` are all printable ones), we're talking 22 minutes before `tr` starts to output anything. But it's more likely going to be hours (in a quick test, I can see `strings` writing a block every 1 to 2 blocks read, and the output blocks contain about 30% of newline characters, so I'd expect it'd need to read at least 3 blocks before `tr` has 4096 characters to output).

To avoid that, you could do:

```
< /dev/random stdbuf -o0 strings --bytes 1 | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n\t '
```

`stdbuf` is a GNU command (also found on some BSDs) that alters the stdio buffering of commands via an LD_PRELOAD trick.

Note that instead of `strings`, you can use `tr -cd '[:graph:]'` which will also exclude tab, newline and space.

You may want to fix the locale to `C` as well to avoid possible future surprises with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: wow impressive explanation.

Comment: Amazing! Great explanation and solution. I've always used `cat` 'uselessly' because I never liked redirecting stdin at the end of a pipeline, now I can 'save a process' and still have readable commands. My final solution was `< /dev/random stdbuf -o0 tr -Cd '[:graph:]' | stdbuf -o0 head --bytes 32`

Comment: @AaronJLang, good point about `[:graph:]`. I had forgotten about that one.

Comment: @AaronJLang, you don't need the `stdbuf` for `head -c32` unless you want to allow it to write the data as soon as it's got it (like in several chunks instead of one 32byte chunk as soon as it's got them)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I tried it without `head` first, but preferred being able to see the progress of my entropy generation

Comment: In my opinion, /dev/urandom is amply sufficient for the author's use. If someone were curious as to how, specifically, urandom works compared to random, I'd suggest reading the comments at the top of the driver in drivers/char/random.c of the kernel source tree. The comments mention an analysis of the PRNG and it's implementation. Hopefully, this paper will answer the question "just how more or less random is urandom compared to random?" Available here: http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/251.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Generating random numbers for many security applications requires sufficient entropy — entropy measures how unpredictable the randomness is. A deterministic processor cannot generate entropy, so entropy must come from the outside — either from a hardware component with non-deterministic behavior, or from other factors that are sufficiently hard to reproduce, such as the timing of user actions (that's where wiggling the mouse comes in). Once sufficient entropy is available, cryptography can be used to generate a practically unlimited stream of random numbers.

Linux works by accumulating entropy in a pool, then using cryptography to produce acceptable random numbers both through `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`. The difference is that `/dev/random` applies an extremely conservative entropy calculation that reduces the estimate of the entropy in the pool for every byte that it generates, whereas `/dev/urandom` does not concern itself with the amount of entropy in the pool.

If the estimate of entropy in the pool is too low, `/dev/random` blocks until more entropy can be accumulated. This can severely cripple the rate at which `/dev/random` can produce output. This is what you're observing here. It has nothing to do with `tr`; but `strings` reads output with buffering, so it has to read a full buffer (a few KB) from `/dev/random` just to produce at least one byte of input.

[`/dev/urandom` is perfectly acceptable for generating a cryptographic key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key), because entropy does not in fact decrease in any perceptible way. (If you keep your machine running for longer than the universe has existed, you can't neglect these considerations, but otherwise you're good.) There is only one case where `/dev/urandom` is not good, which is on a freshly installed system that hasn't had time to generate entropy yet, or a freshly booted system that boots from read-only media.

Eliminating `strings` from your boot chain will probably speed up your process. Below `tr` will filter non-printing chars:

```
</dev/random LC_ALL=C tr -dc '!-~'
```

But **you can use `/dev/urandom` here**, as long as you take care not to generate passwords on a system that hasn't had time to accumulate sufficient entropy. You can check the level of Linux's entropy pool in `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` (if you use `/dev/random`, the figure in this file will be conservative, possibly very much so).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/dev/urandom` to get high-quality (pseudo)random numbers, and `/dev/random` only when you absolutely need random numbers that are really unpredictable. An attacker below NSA's resources will have a *very* hard time to crack `/dev/urandom` (and don't forget about [rubber hose cryptography](http://xkcd.org/538)). The kernel fills a buffer with "really random" bytes, that is what `/dev/random` gives. Sadly the rate at which those are generated is low, so reading a lot from from `/dev/random` *will* stall waiting for randomness.

You might consider using [random.org](http://www.random.org) or its [password generator](http://www.random.org/passwords), or one of the many, many random password generators that are floating around, take a look at e.g. [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line) for a few command line tips (not that I'd recommend all of them, but they should give you ideas), or you could use something like `mkpasswd(1)` (here on Fedora 19 part of `expect-5.45-8.fc19.x86_64`).

Answer (score 0):

To generate passwords use `pwgen`. You may want to add number on command line to generate that length passwords.